# How do I remove the frame from a can light without attic access?

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

I am replacing my can light, operated by a switch with a led wafer light in a space without attic access. I have removed the 3 screws from the can fixture and removed it completely. The trouble I am having is removing the frame to the which the can fixture was and the junction box is attached to. The frame is secured to joists and covered again with a small piece of wood. How do I remove that frame?
Part 2 - I would like to add another light with its own switch off the above light but I have no other wires other than the ground, black & white. If I use only those wires, won’t my new additional light operate off of the present switch as opposed to it’s own even though I connect another piece of wire from the new light to the new switch?
Many thanks!

Comment: picture would help

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that we work on a one question at a time basis. While planning ahead for the 2nd light installation is a good idea, the wiring for it is a different question than the removal of the old can light. Please [edit] this 2nd question out, then as a whole new question about it.

Comment: While pictures would definitely help, I wonder if removing the old mounting frame is really necessary. Can you simply mount the new wafer light into the space available and leave the old frame there?

Comment: Where is the existing switch? Where are you adding the additional switch?  (This part should really be submitted as a separate question.)

Comment: I wanted to remove the gram to give myself more room and I wasn’t certain whether the gram would interfere with the water light but in testing the setup, it worked just fine.

Comment: To Mr FreeMan and Mr. Butterworth: Upon taking your advice regarding submitting another question regarding the switch, I found similar questions to mine and will research whether or not I have a neutral wire at my current switch. Thank you, this was first time posting.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the old frame is what the junction box is secured to, removing it is not only "probably not needed" it's "probably not allowed, unless replacing the junction box with a different junction box, properly secured."

Just connect the wafer light in the hole left behind, or make a bigger hole if needed to install it. Ignore the old frame, use the junction box.

From this location, you can't install a light with its own switch (unless you like hacky smart-bulb solutions) as this location only has switched hot from the switch controlling this location.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The new wafer light has its own junction box but I will just leave the old one in place. As far as installing a separate switch I found this on your forum but I need clarification to understand it better:   https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/100644